# UI issues after private pod installation

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

I created a private pod and installed on the another application.
Before installation the UI is proper and after installing this private pod the frames for UI elements compressed.

Not sure why this is happening.
Please point me in right direction for resolution.

Using Xcode 14.2.

Comment: Can you provide more information? Like the code you're building UI or some screenshots before and after pod integration. I am thinking about public extensions inside your private pod.

Comment: Finally figured out the issue. Thanks for the comment provided @son. It is happening due to an extension written for overriding UILabel intrinsic size.

Answer (score -1):

You can debug views in Xcode by using the View Debugger (the 3D-looking icon in the debug bar) - this might help in identifying what's going wrong.